# google plus login integration

Tags: android, eclipse, google-signin

I need to integrate google login in one of my apps, but the problem is that app in eclipse and for that, I need a library for that but didn't find a library for eclipse. I tried with google play service library, but googleSignInOPtion (GSO) is not imported into the project.

Comment: simply convert project to android studio  its take 3-5 mins

Comment: Why don't you just open the Eclipse project in Android Studio? It's been deprecated for Android development for years

Comment: Or you can figure out how to convert your Eclipse project into Gradle based, but that's sounds like more work

Comment: @VishalPatel

The project has too many libraries, and I tried but its give errors.

Comment: Migrate to android-studio ASAP to access simple steps. Refre https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: then try to resolve ,it dear every migrating step have inteligent work . u can find every issue in stackoverflow.